# How to get ALL submissions and comments posted by a list of redditors?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I need to get all the submissions and comments posted on Reddit for a list of usernames. I've created a *redditor* instance in `PRAW`:

```
import praw  
reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id='client_id',
                client_secret='client_secret',
                user_agent='Crawling (by /u/username)',
                username='username',
                password='password')
redditor = reddit.redditor('username1')
```

So I can get new submissions through this line of code:

```
redditor.submissions.new()
```

But I'm wondering how can I get ALL submissions and comments for a username?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get more submissions from a user change the `limit` attribute of the `new` method. By default I believe the value of `limit` is 25, but you can raise the limit with this line.

```
    redditor.submissions.new(limit=1000) #you can use any number in place of 1000
```